# Mongoose model references and CRUD

Tags: angularjs, node.js, crud, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I'm building a very basic 'TODO' app with MEAN stack. I'm testing endpoints with google's Postman, and have started troubleshooting on the front end. Currently the user can sign-up, login, and logout.  When I try to add a 'todo' item in postman, it creates the item, but it does not add to the user object(maybe this is because there's no way to be 'logged in' while testing in postman?). And when I login on the front end and try to create a todo item ('test') I get the following terminal error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token t
at parse (/Users/AdamShaleen/code/todo/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
```

Here's some code snippets

```
// server endpoint
app.post('/todo', todoController.createTODO);

// full function definition
createTODO: function(request, response, next) {
    TODO.create(request.body, function(error, serverResponse) {
        if (error) {
            return response.status(500).send(error);
        }
        else {
        response.status(200).send(serverResponse);
        }
    });
},

// User Model
var User = new Schema ({
email: {type: String, index: true, trim: true, required: true, unique: true},
password: {type: String, required: true},
todo: [
    {
        id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TODO'}
    }
]

// Todo model
var todoSchema = new Schema ({
item: {type: String}});

// Angular Service
this.createTodo = function(newTODO) {
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/todo',
    data: newTODO
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
});};

// Angular controller
$scope.addTODO = function() {
service.createTodo($scope.newTODO).then(function(response) {
    $scope.todos = response;
});};

// HTML
<input ng-model="newTODO" placeholder="New TODO"></input>
<button type="button" ng-click="addTODO(newTODO)">Add TODO</button>
```

Thanks for any suggestions or insight.  I'm very new to this.

Comment: What version of `body-parser` are you using?  That error message seems to be calling out a failure to parse the json file in the `body-parser` package itself

Comment: According to my package.json file it's version 1.15.2.

Comment: What does the JSON object you are sending look like?  Also, have you tried `JSON.stringify()`-ing it before sending it?